# What is the correct flow for login-logout members system using Cookies + PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I was wondering what should be the flow when creating a members login-logout system which uses both sessions & cookies.
I've been thinking about the following flow :

> 1. Login - create both cookie and session params
> 2. Each page, check for session params for login, if didn't find, go to cookie to get login params
> 3. Logout - delete both cookie & sessions params.

Is this the correct usage of cookies & sessions ?

Thank you

Comment: Why is there a difference between cookies and session? Starting a session in PHP creates a cookie, but you never interact with it directly.

Comment: If you are setting the session why are you considering cookies. Make login entirely based on session

Comment: Actually it's a requirement I have to deal with , on the wide aspect, it's a kind of backup for when the server session data is lost.

Comment: If you're dealing with HTTP sessions you are dealing with cookies already. The cookie carries the session id across requests to keep track of it. I don't know what kind of login params you wan't to keep in your cookie scheme but it sounds scary :)

Answer (score 0):

believe you are on the right track by using them in this way, for example I use not only the sessions cookies.